# Prevent dropdown close when click outside

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

I created a CDropdown with a CInput inside. I don't want the dropdown auto close when I click outside because I want to copy text somewhere and paste to CInput. How can that be? Thanks for your help.

```
<CDropdown :show.sync="isShow">
  <template>
    <CInput 
      label="Sample label"
      type="text" />
  </template>
</CDropdown>
```

Comment: there must be a `blur` event that handles the dropdown hide functionality. try to override it maybe...

Comment: I found click event by CClickaway.js. It works when I removed using chrome dev tool. But it's can't be removed by JQuery.off(). So I don't know how to remove it by code 

Answer (score 0):

Finally I do it by read sourcecode of CDropdown and do workaround:

First, set ref to CDropdown:

```
<CDropdown ref="refDropdown" :show.sync="isShow">
```

Then override hide() function of CDropdown, be sure to call $forceUpdate() to update the directive of CDropdown:

```
this.$refs.refDropdown.hide = function() {
  console.log("Prevented hide");
}
this.$refs.refDropdown.$forceUpdate();
```